# Random Numbers and Counting Occurrences in a Loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm very new to Java and currently have an assignment dealing with loops and random numbers. The question is the following: Modify ThrowingPairsOfDice.java to count and the number of times the pair sums to 2, sums to 3, sums to 4, sums to 5, and sums to 6. Display your results.

This is the code that needs to be modified:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThrowingPairsOfDice
{

/**
 * main method simulates throwing 2 dice 1,000,000 times
 * 
 */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random die1 = new Random();
        Random die2 = new Random();
        int throwOfDice=0;

        System.out.println("How many times should I throw two dice?");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numberOfTimes = kb.nextInt();

        // throw the dice the number of times requested

        for (int i=1;i<=numberOfTimes;i++)
        {
            int toss1 =die1.nextInt(5)+1;
            int toss2 =die2.nextInt(5)+1;
            throwOfDice = toss1 + toss2;
            System.out.println(toss1+ "+" +toss2+ "= " +throwOfDice);
        }

    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to modify this program to count the number of times the pair of dice will sum to the given values, so help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand the code you have posted? Sum to what given values?

Comment: The question that Elliot had asked still stands, do you understand the code you had posted?

Comment: @jprez I would *strongly* suggest that you sit down, think this through, possibly go to your TA's office hours and ask questions.  The answers you are getting here are using some more advanced concepts than you've likely been introduced to (Map and switch are the two examples here) that may cause you to miss the goal of what your professor is trying to teach. The constraints that you have for what you've been shown compared to what we know of the innards of the Java libraries may lead to significant mismatches between what you should be learning and writing and the answers you get here.

Comment: I would also suggest giving [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) a read from Programmers.SE meta's site which goes into a number of the difficulties that asking homework questions on Stack Exchange can lead to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of extra variables to store the # totals. In my answer I use the array sum[] and reference it using the sum of the die minus two.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThrowingPairsOfDice
{

/**
 * main method simulates throwing 2 dice 1,000,000 times
 * 
 */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random die1 = new Random();
        Random die2 = new Random();
        int throwOfDice=0;
        int [] sum = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};


        System.out.println("How many times should I throw two dice?");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numberOfTimes = kb.nextInt();

        // throw the dice the number of times requested

        for (int i=1;i<=numberOfTimes;i++)
        {
            int toss1 =die1.nextInt(5)+1;
            int toss2 =die2.nextInt(5)+1;
            throwOfDice = toss1 + toss2;
            System.out.println(toss1+ "+" +toss2+ "= " +throwOfDice);
            if (throwOfDice < 7) sum[throwOfDice - 2]++;
        }

        for (int i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("# of throws totalling " + (i + 2) + " = " + sum[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be surprised if `switch` has been introduced to the students yet... and in this case, its completely unnecessary.  `sum[throwOfDice - 2]++;` would work without any branching necessary... and also handles the situation where throwOfDice is greater than 6 (though I do note that is the requirements as written in the question).

Comment: given that the bulky `switch` statement is unnecessary to complete the assignment I removed it and replaced it with `sum[throwOfDice - 2]++;` along with an `if` statement to limit the die totals stored to 2-6

Answer (score 0):

You only new one `Random` instance to generate two random `int` values, you could use `printf()` to get formatted output and `if` and `else if` to sum your dice. Something like,

```
Random die = new Random(); // <-- only need one.
// The number of sides to the die.
int sides = 6;
// Variables to count the results
int rolled2 = 0;
int rolled3 = 0;
int rolled4 = 0;
int rolled5 = 0;
int rolled6 = 0;

// throw the dice the number of times requested
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfTimes; i++) {
    int toss1 = 1 + die.nextInt(sides);
    int toss2 = 1 + die.nextInt(sides);
    int throwOfDice = toss1 + toss2;
    System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n", toss1, toss2, throwOfDice);
    if (throwOfDice == 2) {
        rolled2++;
    } else if (throwOfDice == 3) {
        rolled3++;
    } else if (throwOfDice == 4) {
        rolled4++;
    } else if (throwOfDice == 5) {
        rolled5++;
    } else if (throwOfDice == 6) {
        rolled6++;
    }
}
System.out.printf("2 = %d, 3 = %d, 4 = %d, 5 = %d, 6 = %d%n", rolled2,
        rolled3, rolled4, rolled5, rolled6);
```